# Combinatorics for starters: Arranging three numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I have three numbers, $a_1$, $a_2$, and $a_3$, and every number is between $0$ and $6$.(including both,talking about integers).
I want to arrange them such that $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq a_3$.
How many options do I have?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have a question.

Comment: sorry,edited...

Comment: When you say "between" are you including or excluding $0$ and $6$? Also, by "numbers", do you mean "integers"?

Comment: including both,only integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the most direct way to see this is as follows:

Make selections for $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ by placing balls into the bins for integers $0$ through $6$ then label $a_k$ with the selections in weakly decreasing order.

For example:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
\hline & \bullet & & & & \bullet\: \bullet &\\
\end{array}$$

is the selection $(a_1,a_2,a_3)=(5,5,1)$.

This selection can be viewed simply in terms of $3$ balls and $6$ dividers of the $7$ bins:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
 & \bullet & & & & \bullet\: \bullet &\\
\end{array}$$

Thus, to count all possible selections we simply count arrangements of $6$ identical bars and $3$ identical balls.

Basic combinatorics tells us that there are

> $$\frac{(6+3)!}{6!\, 3!}=3\cdot 4\cdot 7 = 84\tag{Answer}$$

of these.

You may have spotted that this is the binomial coefficient $\binom{6+3}{3}$.

In general, for the selection of $k$ weakly decreasing integers from a set of $n$ concurrent integers, there are

> $$\binom{n-1+k}{k}$$

possible selections.

Answer (score 2):

Once you pick the numbers, there is only one order allowed.  You can pick three distinct numbers in $7 \choose 3$ ways, three the same in $7$ ways and two of one and one of another in $7 \cdot 6$ ways for a total ${7 \choose 3}+7+7\cdot 6=84$

Answer (score 1):

OK, just try some things and see what happens:

If $a_1 = 6$, and $a_2 = 6$, then $a_3$ can be anywhere from $0$ to $6$, so 7 options like this.

If $a_1 = 6$, and $a_2 = 5$, then $a_3$ can be anywhere from $0$ to $5$, so 6 options like this.

Aha! So for $a_1 = 6$ we have $7 + 6 + ...+1$ options

And likewise, for $a_2 = 5$ we get $6 + 5 + ... + 1$ options

And this goes all the way down to $a_1=0$ where of course you have only 1 option ($a_2$ and $a_3$ are 0 as well).

So, you have $28+21+15+10+6+3+1=84$ options.

A general formula would be:

$$\sum_{a_1=0}^{6}\sum_{a_2=0}^{a_1}{(a_2+1)} =$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{7}\sum_{j=1}^{7}j =$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{7}(\frac{i\cdot (i+1)}{2}) =$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{7}(i^2 + i) =$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \big(\sum_{i=1}^{7}i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{7}i \big)=$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \big(\frac{7\cdot(7+1)\cdot(2\cdot7+1)}{6} + \frac{7\cdot (7 + 1)}{2}\big)=$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \big(\frac{7\cdot8\cdot15}{6} + \frac{7\cdot 8}{2}\big)=$$

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \big(140 + 28)= $$

$$\frac{168}{2}= 84$$